# Repeat function, but when repeated; cleanest way to skip two call for functions

Tags: python, while-loop

```
while True:
    game_info(player_1, player_2, wins_1, wins_2)
    wins_1, wins_2 = move(board, wins_1, wins_2)  # move() sætter et 'tegn' på board og returner win1/win2


    if wins_1 or wins_2 == 1:
        new_round = input("Do you want to play again?\nType yes or no: ").lower()


        if new_round == "yes" or new_round == "y":  # hvis skal spille igen clear board.
            board = [ ['|   ', '|   ', '|   '], ['|   ', '|   ', '|   '], ['|   ', '|   ', '|   '] ]
            print("_____________________________________________________________\n" \
                  "player_2: %s is going to start, with the sign: %s|" % (player_2, sign))


        elif new_round == "no" or new_round == "n":  # hvis ikke: print hvem der vandt flest runder
            pass

        else:
            """HERE I WANT IT TO REPEAT IT ALL EXCEPT FOR THE TWO FIRST "game_info", and "move"  """
```

At the else statement, it should repeat the whole "while True" EXCEPT for the two first "game_info" and "move" functions. Which should be skipped.
That way end up right after the else statement, and ask the players for another round.

Comment: Move the two function call before your while loop?

Comment: short answer is no.
It is supposed to repeat it self many times until there is a winner, when the winner is found.
It will return the value of either win1 or win2 with 1

Comment: And then ask for another game. 
AND if the user misspells the yes or no. it should ask the user again.
Thats why i want to repeat it all BUT skip the two first.

Comment: I would really put it as two nested loops and even make another function for the actual "playing" loop. The way you have it now does for my taste too much in one loop - not too many lines of code, but too many different things.

Comment: As a side note, you should include those details in your question next time. Leaving out details like that just makes us guess a solution. As for your actual solution, you could either do two loops or make a flag that control the first two lines. Either way works... Also define "cleanest".

Comment: I am sorry if I was a little unclear, it is solved though. And I know I could have expressed what I wanted a little better. It was done very quickly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd say you just add a boolean called skip (or anything) set to false outside the loop and change it in the else case.

Then move the functions to be excluded into an

```
if not skip:
    #Functions that might be skipped
```

Should do the job with low effort and in a clean way.

Comment: That was what I thought was the best way too. I just wanted to make sure that it was the cleanest/best way to do it.